# Can I communicate between two JFrames WITHOUT using static variables or methods?

Tags: java, swing, static, jframe, actionlistener

Basically, I'm trying to get the JButton in Frame1 to edit the JLabel in Frame2. I know it can work if I set the JLabel and getLabel() method in Frame2 to static, and have the ActionListener reference Frame1 directly, but I want to know if there's a way to do it without using static variables or methods.

Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;



public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      
      Frame2 f2 = new Frame2();
      f2.pack();
      f2.setLocation(700, 400);
      f2.setVisible(true);

      Frame1 f1 = new Frame1(f2);
      f1.pack();
      f1.setLocation(400, 400);
      f1.setVisible(true);
   }
}

class Frame1 extends JFrame {

   JButton button;

   public Frame1(JFrame f) {
      
      super("Frame 1");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      button = new JButton("Button");

      add(button);
      
      button.addActionListener(new Listener(f.getLabel()));
   }
}

class Frame2 extends JFrame {

   JLabel label;

   public Frame2() {
            
      super("Frame 2");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      
      label = new JLabel("hello");

      add(label);
   }
   
   public JLabel getLabel() {
      return label;
   }  
}

class Listener implements ActionListener {
   
   private JLabel lab;

   public Listener(JLabel lab) {
      this.lab = lab;
   }  
   
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     
      lab.setText("nice");
   }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

EDIT: Here's a compilable version of the code -- label and getLabel() are static, and the ActionListener references JFrame1 directly when it's called. My goal is to have no static variables or methods (outside of main).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;



public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
          
      Frame2 f2 = new Frame2();
      f2.pack();
      f2.setLocation(700, 400);
      f2.setVisible(true);
      
      Frame1 f1 = new Frame1(f2);
      f1.pack();
      f1.setLocation(400, 400);
      f1.setVisible(true);
   }
}

class Frame1 extends JFrame {

   JButton button;

   public Frame1(JFrame f) {
      
      super("Frame 1");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      button = new JButton("Button");

      add(button);
      
      button.addActionListener(new Listener(Frame2.getLabel()));
   }
}

class Frame2 extends JFrame {

   static JLabel label;

   public Frame2() {
            
      super("Frame 2");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      
      label = new JLabel("hello");

      add(label);
   }
   
   public static JLabel getLabel() {
      return label;
   }  
}

class Listener implements ActionListener {
   
   private JLabel lab;

   public Listener(JLabel lab) {
      this.lab = lab;
   }  
   
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     
      lab.setText("nice");
   }
}
```

Comment: Normally you use the Observer pattern for this, which in Swing is implemented with an `ActionListener`.

Comment: can it be done? yes. can you do it? that's a question you should ask yourself. There's messaging, using a queue, You can have them have access to each others instances and use instance methods, you can use the Observer pattern ..

Comment: And I see that the entire code is there and ready to go, the OP just has to put them together in the right order.  Which leads me to believe this is an exam or homework question.  Maybe at least the OP could post some code which actually compiles?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a really nifty [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  I think your studying the tutorial would be a really good idea.

I had to make a bunch of changes to your code to get it to execute.

The main change I made was to keep the reference to the `JLabel` in the `Frame2` class.  I passed an instance of `Frame2` to the `Listener` class.  Just like I did yesterday with your previous question.

Here's the code.  Take the time to study what I did before you ask another question tomorrow.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DoubleJFrameTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Frame2 f2 = new Frame2();
                f2.pack();
                f2.setLocation(700, 400);
                f2.setVisible(true);

                Frame1 f1 = new Frame1(f2);
                f1.pack();
                f1.setLocation(400, 400);
                f1.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class Frame1 extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JButton button;

    public Frame1(Frame2 f) {
        super("Frame 1");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        button = new JButton("Button");
        button.addActionListener(new Listener(f));

        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(panel);
    }
}

class Frame2 extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JLabel label;

    public Frame2() {
        super("Frame 2");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        label = new JLabel("hello");

        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(panel);
    }

    public void setLabelText(String text) {
        label.setText(text);;
    }
}

class Listener implements ActionListener {
    private Frame2 frame;

    public Listener(Frame2 frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frame.setLabelText("nice");
    }

}
```